# TypeError: res.response is undefined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm doing an user authentication using JWT auth in a SPA with Vue/Laravel. I have an issue with the register module, it isn't doing anything when I click the button, I checked Firefox developer edition's console and it throws me the following error:

TypeError: res.response is undefined

This is my code

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card card-default">
        <div class="card-header">Inscription</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="has_error && !success">
                <p v-if="error == 'registration_validation_error'">Error</p>
                <p v-else>Try again later.</p>
            </div>
            <form autocomplete="off" @submit.prevent="register" v-if="!success" method="post">
                <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': has_error && errors.email }">
                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="user@example.com" v-model="email">
                    <span class="help-block" v-if="has_error && errors.email">{{ errors.email }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': has_error && errors.password }">
                    <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" v-model="password">
                    <span class="help-block" v-if="has_error && errors.password">{{ errors.password }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': has_error && errors.password }">
                    <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control" v-model="password_confirmation">
                </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @click="register">Inscription</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                password_confirmation: '',
                has_error: false,
                error: '',
                errors: {},
                success: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            register() {
                var app = this
                this.$auth.register({
                    data: {
                        email: app.email,
                        password: app.password,
                        password_confirmation: app.password_confirmation
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        app.success = true
                        this.$router.push({
                            name: 'Login',
                            params: {
                                successRegistrationRedirect: true
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    error: function (res) {
                        console.log(res.response.data.errors)
                        app.has_error = true
                        app.error = res.response.data.error
                        app.errors = res.response.data.errors || {}
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If this gives some sort of hint I also have this warning in console:

Reason: CORS request did not succeed

I have no idea why is this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a CORS error which means that the server you're making a request to is not allowing requests from your client domain. If you own the server you'll need to add your domain to the list of allowed domains, or if this fails, check that the request method "POST" is allowed.

It looks like you're then getting the 'res.response" error as when the error gets caught in the error function, it's returning an error message which doesn't have a "response" property. Try console.log'ing the "res" response to see what it's giving you and adjust the property you're using from there.